# Laravel 5.1 unit testing authenticated user

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

So after reading through the documentation a couple of times, I'm still confused as to how you can authenticate as a user for unit testing in 5.1. Previously in 4.2 you could use:

```
$user = new User(array('name' => 'John'));
$this->be($user);
```

In 5.1 the example given is:

```
$user = factory('App\User')->create();
$this->actingAs($user)
```

Isn't the factory just returning a User?  If I attempt to use `$user = new User(array('name' => 'John'));` I get an error because `actingAs` expects an `Authenticatable`. So how do you authenticate as an existing user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$user = new User(..);`  doesn't give you an existing user either. Try `$user = User::find(1)` to become an existing member. If you meant testing as a non-existing member, you can just include the `DatabaseTransactions` trait which rolls back everything that was created during the test.

Comment: Sorry I was just giving an example, in my current test I am using User::find but I receiver the `obj is not an Autheticatable` error.

Comment: Are you sure your model is implementing "Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable" ? Plus, I'm assuming you're using the fully qualified class name and not getting any errors while instantiating, right? Could you do a var_dump() on App\User::find(1)?

Comment: Wow thank you, I took a look at the User model and the changes to upgrade from 4.2 -> 5 were not saved. Implemented the changes again and the unit test works.

Comment: I am a unit testing newb, but I think `User::find(1)` makes the test method hit the database, disqualifying it as a unit test.

Comment: This is a crap answer and OP should add his answer